# Permission denied @ rb_sysopen / macOS / brew

Tags: ruby, macos

I try to run brew, but then I get this error:

```sh
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- concurrent/concurrent_ruby_ext (LoadError)
    31: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    30: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    29: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    27: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    26: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    21: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    20: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `load_native_extensions'
    18: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `each'
    17: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:30:in `block in load_native_extensions'
    16: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_extension_loader.rb:62:in `try_load_c_extension'
    15: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    14: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:212:in `try_activate'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `find_by_path'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:826:in `stubs'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:788:in `installed_stubs'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:795:in `map_stubs'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:795:in `flat_map'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:795:in `each'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:798:in `block in map_stubs'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in `gemspec_stubs_in'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in `select'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:204:in `valid?'
     2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:114:in `data'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:114:in `open'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:114:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications/escape-0.0.4.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
```

I think it is, because I tried to install a gem with sudo.
Is there a way to fix it, without the reinstallation from macOS?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the gem you installed with sudo?

Comment: BTW, I can recommend [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) along with [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) to install / manage Ruby versions. You might want to give it a try once you've fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and fixed it as follows.

`sudo chmod a+r /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/*.gemspec`

You most probably ran `sudo gem install` with read permission turned off for others. Try `umask 22` next time you run gem install and see if that helps.